# read a csv file and translate it in uppercase and store it in another csv file with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, uppercase

i need to read a csv file and translate it in uppercase and store it in another csv file with python
I have this code:

```
import csv
with open('data_csv.csv', 'rb') as f:
    header = next(f).strip().split(',')
    reader = csv.DictReader((l.upper() for l in f), fieldnames=header)
    for line in reader:
        print  line
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

but  I can not find the right result

Comment: What is "the right result" for you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to read the header separately. If you don't provide a `fieldnames` argument to `DictReader()`, the header is read **automatically**. Next, don't print your lines, you have now read the whole file and dropped all the lines.

Open both the input and output files in the same `with` statement, you can then write lines directly to the output. There is **no need** to use the `csv` module here, because you don't need to parse out the rows, then form the rows into lines again.

Just loop over the file, uppercase the *lines*, and write out the result:

```
with open('data_csv.csv', 'r') as input, open('test.csv', 'w') as output:
    output.writelines(line.upper() for line in input)
```

Comment: thnx but  he gives me this error Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.csv'

Comment: @kazz: ah, my mistake. The output file should be opened for writing of course. Corrected.

Comment: @kazz: it was opened for *reading*, which requires that the file exists. You made the same mistake in your code.